# PL/SQL: Error "PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to" triggered for table of numbers

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to call an API using the exact procedure signature, but somehow the table of numbers I don't think is recognize correctly.

API definition:

```
TYPE NUMLIST IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY VARCHAR2(50);

PROCEDURE GETSERVICES_API
(
   I_DIMOBJID IN NUMBER, I_OBJECTID IN NUMBER, I_FILTER IN NUMBER, 
   O_ERRORCODE OUT NUMBER, O_ERRORTEXT OUT VARCHAR2, O_SERVICELIST OUT NUMLIST
);
```

My call of API:

```
DECLARE

   TYPE NUMLIST IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY VARCHAR2(50);
   lt_SERVICELIST              NUMLIST;

   ls_errortext             varchar2(100);
   ln_errorcode             number;

BEGIN


    PKGCOMSUPPORT_SERVICE.GETSERVICES_API(I_DIMOBJID => 6,
                                          I_OBJECTID => 5263,
                                          I_FILTER => 3,
                                          O_ERRORCODE => ln_errorcode,
                                          O_ERRORTEXT => ls_errortext,
                                          O_SERVICELIST => lt_SERVICELIST);

END;
```

When I run my call of API I got: PLS-00306: wrong number of types of arguments in call to 'GETSERVICE_API

Any idea why? Thanks

Comment: did you try to put your NUMLIST type declaration outside your pl/sql block?

Comment: No, I haven't tried, but should be the same thing.

Comment: I don't think you can create types in a pl/sql block, they are database objects

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason why you are facing the `PLS-00306` error  is incompatibility of `NUMLIST` collection type, defined in the package specification and `NUMLIST` collection type defined in the anonymous PL/SQL block. Even though definitions of those two collection types are the same, they are not compatible.  In your anonymous PL/SQL block you have to declare and then pass into the `GETSERVICES_API` procedure a variable of  `PKGCOMSUPPORT_SERVICE.NUMLIST` data type.

```
create or replace package PKG as
  type t_numlist is table of number index by varchar2(50);
  procedure SomeProc(p_var in pkg.t_numlist);
end;
/

create or replace package body PKG as
  procedure someproc(p_var in pkg.t_numlist) is
  begin
    null;
  end;
end;
/

declare
  type t_numlist is table of number index by varchar2(50);
  l_var t_numlist;
begin
  pkg.someproc(l_var);
end;

ORA-06550: line 5, column 3:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SOMEPROC'

declare
  --type t_numlist is table of number index by varchar2(50);
  l_var pkg.t_numlist;
begin
  pkg.someproc(l_var);
end;

anonymous block completed
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the type definition is invalid.  To create a table 'type' you need something like the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE NUMLIST AS OBJECT (COLUMN1 VARCHAR2(50));
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this:

```
CREATE TYPE NUMLIST AS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY VARCHAR2(50);

DECLARE

   lt_SERVICELIST              NUMLIST;

   ls_errortext             varchar2(100);
   ln_errorcode             number;

BEGIN


    PKGCOMSUPPORT_SERVICE.GETSERVICES_API(I_DIMOBJID => 6,
                                          I_OBJECTID => 5263,
                                          I_FILTER => 3,
                                          O_ERRORCODE => ln_errorcode,
                                          O_ERRORTEXT => ls_errortext,
                                          O_SERVICELIST => lt_SERVICELIST);

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had also the PLS-00306 error, but the cause was different. In my case, I was using wrong name of argument. I've got procedure: `FUNCTION get_card_list(p_clob_in IN CLOB, o_clob_out OUT CLOB)`

The arguments names are **p_clob_in** and **o_clob_out**, so I should call this procedure by: `get_card_list(p_clob_in=>inner, o_clob_out=>outer)`
or `get_card_list(inner, outer)`, but I was using wrong argument names: **p_xml** & **o_xml**: `get_card_list(p_xml=>inner, o_xml=>outer)`

This YT video helps me a lot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xwMVL3Z_vn8