# PL-SQL type declared in specification not compatible with parameter of body procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this type defined in my package specification:

```
TYPE NUMLIST IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY VARCHAR2(50);
```

and a global variable as well defined in the specifications:

```
G_SERVICES           NUMLIST;
```

I want in my body to call a procedure having this definition:

```
PROCEDURE filterAandB( pin_filter_type         IN NUMBER
                     , piota_initial_gservices IN OUT NUMLIST)
```

like this:

```
filterAandB( pin_filter_type        => I_FILTER
           , pita_initial_gservices => liota_initial_gservices);
```

Need to mention that the procedure is private so the definition is in the body

```
PROCEDURE filterAandB( pin_filter_type         IN NUMBER
                     , piota_initial_gservices IN OUT NUMLIST);
```

I'm getting

> Error: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
>   'FILTERAANDB' Line: 2731

I also tried to call it form a block and still the same error.

Looking to similar issues I found that you need to declare the type of the parameter as

```
pkgcomsupport_service.NUMLIST;
```

due to some incompatibilites , look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543343/pl-sql-error-pls-00306-wrong-number-or-types-of-arguments-in-call-to-trigger?answertab=votes#tab-top) thread, so

```
liota_initial_gservices pkgcomsupport_service.NUMLIST;
```

is declared like this and also the parameter in the declaration of the procedure is of type

`pkgcomsupport_service.NUMLIST;`

but still same error.

Comment: what is the datatype of `I_FILTER`? Also, is the procedure containing the call to filteraandb in the same package body as filteraandb?

Comment: `NUMBER`, I'm pretty sure not `I_FILTER` is the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you've said, I don't see a problem. However, your explanation is not very clear - it would be much more helpful if you could produce an example package (spec + body) that reproduces the error that you are getting.

Here's a package that I knocked up to try and mimic what you're describing:

```
create or replace package test as
  TYPE NUMLIST IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY VARCHAR2(50);
  G_SERVICES           NUMLIST;

  PROCEDURE test2(in_numlist numlist);
END TEST;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST AS
  PROCEDURE test1 (in_number NUMBER,
                   in_numlist numlist)
  IS
  BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('this works!');
  END;

  PROCEDURE test2(in_numlist numlist)
  IS
    v_num NUMBER := 1;
  BEGIN
    test1(v_num, in_numlist);
  END;
END TEST;
/
```

To call it, I run the following:

```
DECLARE
  v_numlist test.numlist;
BEGIN
  test.test2(v_numlist);
END;
/
```

And this is the output I get:

```
this works!
```

So, no problems there. If the above test case doesn't accurately represent your situation, I suggest you edit your question to include a complete test-case which demonstrates your issue so that we have a better chance of diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Send `v_numlist` as parameter from the block to the procedure

Comment: I've edited my answer to include your suggestion and still experience no issues. You can see that in the anonymous block calling the test.test2 procedure, I've declare the v_numlist variable to be the test.numlist datatype. That's because that's the datatype that test.test2 is expecting.

Comment: yes, I made a stupid mistake and put in the call of the procedure parameter `pita_initial_gservices` when in the definition of the procedure was `piota_initial_gservices`, sorry and thanks