# wrong number of arguments or type when call procedure in Oracle 12C database

Tags: database, oracle, procedure

Created a package in oracle 12C database and have C# code to call it. Got error "wrong number of arguments or type" when executeNoQuery as below. Checked package signature and compared with code in C#. Could not figure out the issue. The only type not sure is to map Oracle number(10). Tried to map it with OracleDbType.varchar2, int32, int64 and Long but got all the same error. Below is package signature and C# code. I would like to know what is wrong on what I did and someone can help.

Package:

```
create or replace PACKAGE GETIMPOSITION AS    
   TYPE impTyp IS TABLE OF varchar2(200);
   TYPE impNm IS TABLE OF varchar2(255);  
   TYPE impTax IS TABLE OF char(1);
   TYPE impIncld IS TABLE OF char(1);
   TYPE impId IS TABLE OF varchar2(8);
   TYPE impSkuId IS TABLE OF number(10,0);
   TYPE impPmCd IS TABLE OF varchar2(15);

   /* Get data from each OUT parameter */
   procedure RMS_GET_IMPOSITION_INFO (
      O_IMPOSITIONTYPES OUT impTyp,
      O_ERRORDES OUT VARCHAR2,
      O_ERRORCODE OUT VARCHAR2
   ); 
END GETIMPOSITION;
```

C# code:

```
 int[] aRraybindingSize = new int[2000];
    List<string> empty = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arrBindingSize.Length; i++)
    {
       empty.Add(string.Empty);
    }

    using (OracleConnection database = new OracleConnection(connString))
    {
    OracleCommand dbCommand = database.CreateCommand();
    dbCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    dbCommand.CommandText = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("StoredProcedureNameIMPSEX");

    OracleParameter[] oracleParam = new OracleParameter[3];
    oracleParam[0] = new OracleParameter("O_IMPOSITIONTYPES", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 100);
    oracleParam[0].CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
    oracleParam[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; 
    oracleParam[0].Size = empty.Count;
    oracleParam[0].ArrayBindSize = arrBindingSize;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrBindingSize.Length; i++)
    {
        oracleParam[0].ArrayBindSize[i] = 100;
    }
    oracleParam[0].Value = empty.ToArray();
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add(oracleParam[0]);
```

oracleParam[1] = new OracleParameter("O_ERRORDES", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 512);
        oracleParam[1].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

```
    oracleParam[2] = new OracleParameter("O_ERRORCODE", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 512);
    oracleParam[2].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

    dbCommand.Parameters.AddRange(oracleParam);
    database.Open();
    int status = dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
 }
```

Changed procedure to have JUST one OUTPUT array (Shown above) but still got the same error. If change it to not be an array, the procedure and C# code got correct data from database call. To me when C# code talk procedure, they don't understand each other what are the PLSQLAssociativeArray. Adding status as return parameters is not the issue. This is no oracle function call. Do executeNonQuery without return value is fine so line int status can be gone. Any comment on PLSQLAssociativeArray? is that any error. Or procedure need to change?

Comment: When execute to ExecuteNonQuery(), the C# code throw an exception as "wrong number of arguments or type"

Comment: I believe your post is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543343/pl-sql-error-pls-00306-wrong-number-or-types-of-arguments-in-call-to-trigger) and the accepted answer will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jeff. But I run this package using Oracle SQL developer and it works fine. Any thought?

Comment: Create a minimal example using only one parameter until you figure out which one is causing the problem. It could be that there is more than one type that is causing the problem. But by creating a more minimal case, you'll be better able to resolve the problem.

Comment: Good idea. Will try that. Thanks

Comment: Changed package so left one argument. It works fine running using SQL developer and return 500 rows. Now change C# code 
 and left one parameter too as below but still got the same error. Any thought? oracleParam[0] = new OracleParameter("O_IMPOSITIONTYPES", OracleDbType.Varchar2); 
oracleParam[0].CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
oracleParam[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.OutputoracleParam[0].Size = 1000;
oracleParam[0].ArrayBindSize = aRraybindingSize;
for (int i = 0; i < aRraybindingSize.Length; i++)  {
      oracleParam[0].ArrayBindSize[i] = 100;
}

Comment: Changed package so left one argument. It works fine running using SQL developer and return 500 rows. Now change C# code 
 and left one parameter too as below but still got the same error. Any thought? oracleParam[0] = new OracleParameter("O_IMPOSITIONTYPES", OracleDbType.Varchar2); 
oracleParam[0].CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
oracleParam[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;oracleParam[0].Size = 1000;
oracleParam[0].ArrayBindSize = aRraybindingSize;
for (int i = 0; i < aRraybindingSize.Length; i++)  {
      oracleParam[0].ArrayBindSize[i] = 100;
}

Comment: Don't paste code into a comment in response to a comment. Edit your original post to include the conversation (what you learned and the next step).

Comment: Jeff, I changed code in as you recommended. Do you have any suggestion wither on C# code side or procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your status parameter first

```
create or replace PACKAGE GETIMPOSITION AS    
   TYPE impTyp IS TABLE OF varchar2(200);
   TYPE impNm IS TABLE OF varchar2(255);  
   TYPE impTax IS TABLE OF char(1);
   TYPE impIncld IS TABLE OF char(1);
   TYPE impId IS TABLE OF varchar2(8);
   TYPE impSkuId IS TABLE OF number(10,0);
   TYPE impPmCd IS TABLE OF varchar2(15);

   /* Get data from each OUT parameter */
   procedure RMS_GET_IMPOSITION_INFO (
      O_IMPOSITIONTYPES OUT impTyp,
      O_IMPOSITIONNAME OUT impNm,
      O_IMPSTTAXABILITIES OUT impTax,
      O_INCLUDEDINTAXES OUT impIncld,
      O_IMPOSITIONID OUT impId,
      O_IMPSTSKUS OUT impSkuId,
      O_IMPSTPIMS OUT impPmCd,
      O_ERRORDES OUT VARCHAR2,
      O_ERRORCODE OUT VARCHAR2
   ); 
END GETIMPOSITION;



    int[] aRraybindingSize = new int[2000];

    using (OracleConnection database = new OracleConnection(connString))
    {
    OracleCommand dbCommand = database.CreateCommand();
    dbCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    dbCommand.CommandText = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("StoredProcedureNameIMPSEX");

// Return value parameter has to be added first !
                int status = new OracleParameter();
                status.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                status.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(status);

    OracleParameter[] oracleParam = new OracleParameter[9];
    oracleParam[0] = new OracleParameter("O_IMPOSITIONTYPES", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 100);
    oracleParam[0].CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
    oracleParam[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    oracleParam[0].ArrayBindSize = aRraybindingSize;

    oracleParam[1] = new OracleParameter("O_IMPOSITIONNAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 255);
    oracleParam[1].CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
    oracleParam[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    oracleParam[1].ArrayBindSize = aRraybindingSize;

    oracleParam[2] = new OracleParameter("O_IMPSTTAXABILITIES", OracleDbType.Char, 1);
    oracleParam[2].CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
    oracleParam[2].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    oracleParam[2].ArrayBindSize = aRraybindingSize;

    oracleParam[3] = new OracleParameter("O_INCLUDEDINTAXES", OracleDbType.Char, 1);
    oracleParam[3].CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
    oracleParam[3].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    oracleParam[3].ArrayBindSize = aRraybindingSize;

    oracleParam[4] = new OracleParameter("O_IMPOSITIONID", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 8);
    oracleParam[4].CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
    oracleParam[4].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    oracleParam[4].ArrayBindSize = aRraybindingSize;

    oracleParam[5] = new OracleParameter("O_IMPSTSKUS", OracleDbType.Int64);
    oracleParam[5].CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
    oracleParam[5].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    oracleParam[5].Precision = 10;
    oracleParam[5].Scale = 0;
    oracleParam[5].Size = 10;
    oracleParam[5].ArrayBindSize = aRraybindingSize;

    oracleParam[6] = new OracleParameter(`enter code here`"O_IMPSTPIMS", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 15);
    oracleParam[6].CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
    oracleParam[6].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    oracleParam[6].ArrayBindSize = aRraybindingSize;

    oracleParam[7] = new OracleParameter("O_ERRORDES", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 512);
    oracleParam[7].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

    oracleParam[8] = new OracleParameter("O_ERRORCODE", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 512);
    oracleParam[8].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

    dbCommand.Parameters.AddRange(oracleParam);
    database.Open();
    Convert.ToInt32(status.Value) = dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

 }
```